# Matching Everything except specified string regex

Tags: regex

I know that the following regex will match "Value1" or "Value3"

```
 (Value1|Value3)\n([0-9]+)
```

data set

```
Value1
631

Value2
871

Value4G
18813

Value5G
3292

Value1
10621

Value1
10301
```

Is there a way of making it match everything except specified strings?

If I specify not to match Value and Value 3

the result would be

```
Value4G
18813

Value5G
3292
```

Comment: Please do mention which language you are looking to apply this regex?

Comment: Maybe something like [`^Value(?![12]\b)\dG?\n\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1ldYtk/1) which would still allow for things like 'Value1G' but would exclude 'Value1' and 'Value2'? Use capture groups if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^Value(?![1-3]\b)\d.*(?:\n\S.*)*
```

See the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kHFqIk/3) Mind the `m` flag that makes `^` match the start of a line.

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of a line
- `Value` - `Value` string
- `(?![1-3]\b)` - no `1` or `2` or `3` followed with a word boundary are allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d` - a digit
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n\S.*)*` - zero or more lines that start with a non-whitespace char.